# Diffable Snapshot reload section header

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, uitableview, nsdiffabledatasourcesnapshot

When reloading a table view data with `NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot`, the table view will only reload sections that contain differences from the previous snapshot.

I have a table view that contains entries with specific dates. The entries are ordered by sections for the entry week/month/custom date range, based on what the user had chosen in the segment control.

When I have a week section and this week is the only week that exist for this month, the section will not update when the user chooses a different date range and the header will stay the same.

How can I get all section headers to be reloaded regardless of if there is a difference between this and the previous snapshot?

Here is the code for setting up the snapshot:

```swift
struct EntriesSection {

    let date: Date
    var entries: [Entry] = []
}

var sections: [EntriesSection]()

private func setupSnapshot() {

    snapshot = NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<Date, Entry>()

    sections.forEach {
        snapshot.appendSections([$0.date])
        snapshot.appendItems($0.entries, toSection: $0.date)
    }

    dataSource?.apply(snapshot, animatingDifferences: true)
}
```

Results:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue was with the title of the first section which was not changing.

The section is of type `Date` - `NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<Date, Entry>()` and both the week and the month start date was on the same day which is *Dec 1, 2019*.

So as far as the snapshot, the date is still the same, for both week and month.

In order to resolve it, I created an object which is a date range:

```swift
struct DateRange: Hashable {
  let from: Date
  let to: Date
}
```

And then changed the snapshot section type from `Date` to `DateRange`:

`NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<DateRange, Entry>()`

Now, if the start date is the same and the end date changes, the snapshot will know that he needs to update the header.

Answer (score 0):

This works also:

```
var updatedSnapshot = dataSource.snapshot()
updatedSnapshot.reloadSections([.main])
self.dataSource.apply(updatedSnapshot, animatingDifferences: true)
```